# jQuery set the value of elements to default if they are not visible

Tags: jquery

Here is my jQuery snippet

```
 $("#firstBankDetail").hide();
       $("#secondBankDetail").hide();
       $("#thirdBankDetail").hide();
       $("#fourthBankDetail").hide();
       $("#noOfBankDetails").change(function(){
           var value = $(this).val();

           if(value == 0) {
               $("#firstBankDetail").hide();
               $("#secondBankDetail").hide();
               $("#thirdBankDetail").hide();
               $("#fourthBankDetail").hide();
           }
           else if(value == 1) {
               $("#firstBankDetail").show();
               $("#secondBankDetail").hide();
               $("#thirdBankDetail").hide();
               $("#fourthBankDetail").hide();  
           }
           else if(value == 2) {
               $("#firstBankDetail").show();
               $("#secondBankDetail").show();
               $("#thirdBankDetail").hide();
               $("#fourthBankDetail").hide(); 
           }
           else if(value == 3){
               $("#firstBankDetail").show();
               $("#secondBankDetail").show();
               $("#thirdBankDetail").show();
               $("#fourthBankDetail").hide();  
           }
           else if(value == 4){
               $("#firstBankDetail").show();
               $("#secondBankDetail").show();
               $("#thirdBankDetail").show();
               $("#fourthBankDetail").show();
           }

        });
```

It shows the bankDetails based `noOfBankDetails`   dropdown.

Next while submitting i have applied validations on the visible `bankDetail` as shown

```
   $('form').submit(function (event) {
       if($('#firstBankDetail').is(':visible')) {
           if(!validateFirstBankDetails()){
               event.preventDefault();
               return false;
           }
        } 

       if($('#secondBankDetail').is(':visible')) {
          if(!validateSecondBankDetails()){
           event.preventDefault();
           return false;
          }
        }   
       if($('#thirdBankDetail').is(':visible')) {
           if(!validateThirdBankDetails()){
               event.preventDefault();
               return false;
           }
        }   
       if($('#fourthBankDetail').is(':visible')) {
           if(!validateFourthBankDetails()){
               event.preventDefault();
               return false;
           }
        }
   });
```

This works perfectly fine. However there comes an issue when i select dropdown to value 4
and in fourth detail in any field i fill String where double is expected and then again i select dropdown to 2. Then click on submit. In that case validation runs only for two however the data for all 4 are sent server and i get a `NumberFormatException`.

Any Solutions  ???

EDIT : To include

```
function validateFirstBankDetails(){
    var bankDetails0_nameOfBank = document.getElementById("bankDetails0_nameOfBank");
    var bankDetails0_nameOfBranch = document.getElementById("bankDetails0_nameOfBranch");
    var bankDetails0_accountNumber = document.getElementById("bankDetails0_accountNumber");
    var bankDetails0_accountType = document.getElementById("bankDetails0_accountType");

    var bankDetails0_EMIforProposedLoan = document.getElementById("bankDetails0_EMIforProposedLoan");

    if(bankDetails0_accountNumber.value == ""){
        alert("Please Enter the Account No");
        bankDetails0_accountNumber.setAttribute("style","background-color: #ffcccc");   
        return false;
    }

    if(bankDetails0_accountType.value == ""){
        alert("Please Select the Account Type");
        bankDetails0_accountType.setAttribute("style","background-color: #ffcccc");   
        return false;
    }

    if(bankDetails0_EMIforProposedLoan.value == ""){
        alert("Please Enter the EMI for proposed loan");
        bankDetails0_EMIforProposedLoan.setAttribute("style","background-color: #ffcccc");   
        bankDetails0_EMIforProposedLoan.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if(isNaN(bankDetails0_EMIforProposedLoan.value)){
        alert("Proposed EMI must be number only !");
        bankDetails0_EMIforProposedLoan.setAttribute("style","background-color: #ffcccc");   
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: hard to say if we don't see none of the `validateFirstBankDetails()` functions...

Comment: All this code could have been written in a third of these lines. Just a tip.

Comment: The function validateFirstBankDetails() has many such validations and i have tailored it. I am not supposed to make changes in them they are from time when jQuery was not used.